Athena: Enable queries at microsecond timestamp resolution
We store a Parquet data lake with IoT data. The Parquet files contain a timestamp column (microsecond resolution) and various signal value columns like Speed, Altitude etc.
We use Amazon Athena to query the data and AWS Glue to map the schemas via a Python script.
Our problem is that Athena is limited to millisecond resolution for the timestamp. For some use cases we need to be able to query the data as if the timestamp was in microsecond resolution instead.

Are there plans for Athena to eventually support microsecond resolution?

If not, are there ways we can work around this issue if we e.g. modify our Parquet files or the Glue script that maps our Parquet schema?



I don't have access to Athena ATM, but Trino (which Athena engine v3 is based on) supports more precise timestamps (for example via from_iso8601_timestamp_nanos) function and timestamp(p) types. Try checking out if queries like SELECT cast(TIMESTAMP '2020-06-10 15:55:23.383345' as TIMESTAMP(12)) works in Athena.

In the Athena query editor I get the below result from running that query: 2020-06-10 15:55:23.383345000000 - not sure if that indicates that Athena should support timestamps with microsecond resolution? If yes, it is unclear to me how we would make it 'map' the data as such in Glue/Athena

Yes, that means that it does support that. Not sure how this can be done with Glue, but you can try declaring table "manually" and specifying the type.
